# Possible to preview what will rsync do, before overwriting/deleting files?

Tags: backup, sync, rsync

With SyncToy on Windows, I can preview what it will do to my files before commiting the changes. Is it possible to do the same with rsync or something similar?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this command line option:

```
-n, --dry-run               perform a trial run with no changes made
```

Comment: I guess I cant do that same with a GUI tool? like `grsync`?

Comment: oh to do it in `grsync` just add -n in the Additional Options Tab > Textarea

Answer (score -1):

There is a tool called unison that builds on rsync. It provides two-way synchronization with the ability to track deletes. Check your repos or find source/binaries below:

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

Comment: `unison` do not builds on `rsync`, only use a transfer protocol that is in part derived from that of `rsync`.

Comment: Well, we are both partly right.  
  
Unison uses a protocol similar to rsync:  
"It is careful with network bandwidth, and runs well over slow links such as PPP connections. Transfers of small updates to large files are optimized using a compression protocol similar to rsync."  
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/  
  
Unison uses the same rsync algorithm for transfers:  
https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/wiki/index.php?n=Main.UnisonFAQGeneral